# How can I install amf extension in PHP 5 using Ubuntu 8.10?

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to find out on how to install the amf extension in Ubuntu 8.10 in order for the amf flash to work.

I can't seem to find a good tutorial in google.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use pecl?  http://pecl.php.net/package/amfext is where it is.  `sudo pecl install amfext` should work, you might need to tell pecl to use the beta release though.